# groupby iterate with sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code and console output.

```
import pandas as pd

#data
df= pd.DataFrame([{'col1':'a', 'is_open':0}, {'col1':'b', 'is_open':1}])

#1
df = df.sort_values('is_open',ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
# print(df)

#2
for i, d in df.groupby(['col1', 'is_open']):
    print(d)
```

```
  col1  is_open
1    a        0
  col1  is_open
0    b        1
```

I want is_open=1 to be printed out first like below.

```
  col1  is_open
0    b        1
  col1  is_open
1    a        0
```

Sorting dataframe before grouping did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hmm, it should be printed first - I assume your numbers are actually strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Poiuy noted, `groupby` will sort by the grouping key... but it can be turned off.

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'is_open'], sort=False)
```

Comment: This helped me. I inserted the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like the snippet below. Pandas groupBy function defaults to sorting by group keys which are in this case the first column, followed by the second column. Once the values have been grouped and aggregated you can sort the result and iterate through the data frame.

```
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'is_open']).apply(lambda x: x).sort_values('is_open',ascending=False)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Does that work for you? AFAIK the result of `groupby` does not have `.sort_values`

Comment: hmm you're right I assumed that the groupBy would return a normal data frame object instead of a DataFrameGroupBy object. Editing the answer to convert back to a dataframe using an identity function.

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me. Thank you all.

```
import pandas as pd

#data
df= pd.DataFrame([{'col1':'a', 'is_open':0}, {'col1':'b', 'is_open':1}])

#1
# df = df.sort_values('is_open',ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.sort_values('is_open',ascending=True)
# print(df)

#2
for i, d in df.groupby(['col1', 'is_open'], sort=False):
    print(d)
```